# How to Check whether a value is entered in editexts before submitting?

Tags: android, validation, android-edittext

I have around 5 edittexts.When i click submit button,it has to check whether all fields are entered or not.Along with it if any value is not entered,the focus has to go to that desired edittext.If there are many editexts empty,then the focus has to go in top down order.I have used seterror method but when i type in that editext the error msg is not going.After entering values the focus is not going to the next edittext.how to solve this issue?

caseno,dateloss,policy_rep,reg_book,Dri_lic are the different editexts used.I have written code for one editext below

```
caseno.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasfocus)

                {



                     if(!hasfocus && caseno.getText().length()==0)
                        {    
                              new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
                              {

                              @Override
                              public void run() {
                                   //ev2.clearFocus();



                                dateloss.clearFocus();
                                policy_rep.clearFocus();
                                reg_book.clearFocus();
                                Dri_lic.clearFocus();
                                  caseno.requestFocus();
                                  caseno.setError("Enter this field");

                              }
                        }, 100);

                     }





                }
            });



btnsubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {



        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {





            if(caseno!=null||dateloss!=null||policy_rep!=null||reg_book!=null||Dri_lic!=null)
            {


            Send_reportclaim_Async reportsync=new Send_reportclaim_Async();
            reportsync.execute();
            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android provides a `setError()` method for this:

```
if(edttxtDescription.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
{
    edttxtDescription.setError("Please provide description");
}
```

Define a method to check whether your `EditText`s have valid data:

```
private boolean validateEditTexts()
{
    boolean valid = true;

    if(edttxtDescription.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
    {
        edttxtDescription.setError("Please provide description");
        valid = false;
    }

    // Similarly check all your EditTexts here and set the value of valid

    ......
    ......

    return valid;

}
```

To validate all your `EditTexts`, call `validateEditTexts()` which will return `true` or `false` accordingly.

```
btnsubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(validateEditTexts()){

            Send_reportclaim_Async reportsync=new Send_reportclaim_Async();
            reportsync.execute();

        }
    }
});
```

Try this. This will work.

Comment: ok when i click submit button the error msg shows.When i enter values in that editext still the error(set error message) is showing.I think till the next button click the error will be showing.

Comment: where should i use that method inside button click??

Comment: No the seterror message wont go when i edit in that editbox....at this point i tried some simple code..which is helping...I dont know whether any update will come....Appreciate your response Zygotelnit

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

```
for(EditText edit : editTextList){
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(edit.getText()){
        // EditText is empty

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maintain array of EditText references: Like

```
EditText[] allEts = { caseno, dateloss, policy_rep, reg_book, Dri_lic };
```

Write the below code in onClick of submit button:

```
    for (EditText editText : allEts) {
         String text = editText.getText().toString();
         if (text.length() == 0) {
            editText.setError("enter this field");
            editText.requestFocus();
            break;
        }
    }
```

And, implement addTextChangedListener for all edittexts to clear the error after entering the text.

```
    caseno.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            Editable text = caseno.getText();
            if (caseno.getError() != null && text != null
                    && text.length() > 0) {
                caseno.setError(null);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this on your button click

```
if(!textView1.toString().isEmpty() && !textView2.toString().isEmpty() && ...)
{
 ............
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) create this method

```
public static boolean isNullOrEmpty(String input) {
    return input == null || input.isEmpty();
}
```

2) send data to it for validation

```
  boolean answer = isNullOrEmpty(editText.gettext().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    btnsubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {





        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {




 if(TextUtils.isEmpty(caseno.getText().toString()))
             {


         caseno.requestFocus();
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Enter the required fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            return;
         }

            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(dateloss.getText().toString()))
             {


                dateloss.requestFocus();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Enter the required fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            return;
         }

}
```

Currently this setup is working for me...Thnks those who answered